# Getting a file from my local server and uploading it to a remote server using php

Tags: php, ftp

I know there are many posts about this issue however I cannot find one single answer on here that describes EXACTLY what I am trying to do and I have been searching for HOURS...so hopefully you all can help me and steer me in the right direction, the main thing I cannot figure out how to do is get the source file and pass that to my update function where I will ftp that file to the remote server...

Basically what I am trying to do is the following:

1) Get a file from my local host (ex. /home/user/public_html/file.php)
2) Upload that file to a remote server of one of my clients (I have all of their FTP information stored in my database and can connect to their server just fine)
3) If the file exists on the remote server, have it over write with the one.

Now, I have tried ftp_get to get the file but that is not what I want to do because I don't need to re-write or store the same file to the local server...

Here's what I have so far...

Any help is much appreciated and I do apologize if this is answered some where else I just didn't see it! :)

**AS AN UPDATE TO THIS I JUST THOUGHT OF SOMETHING...**

Why do I even have to get the local file via ftp? Shouldn't I just be able to get the local file some other way and pass that to my update function where it will upload that file to the remote server?

**update.php**

```
$updater = new updater($accountInfo['ftp_user'],$accountInfo['ftp_pass'],$accountInfo['host']);
$file = "relative/path/to/my/file";
$source = $updater->getFile($file);
$updater->update($source,$file);
```

**my update class**

```
class updater {
var $ftp_user = "";
var $ftp_pass = "";
var $ftp_host = "";

function __construct($user,$pass,$host) {
$this->ftp_user = $user;
$this->ftp_pass = $pass;
$this->ftp_host = $host;    
}



 function getFile($file) {
$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen($file, 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://domain.com/".$file); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ftpuser:ftppass");
$returnFile = curl_exec($curl);
return $returnFile;
}

function update($source,$file) {
    echo("Source: ".$source."<BR>");
    echo("File: ".$file."<BR>");
$connection = ftp_connect($this->ftp_host);

$login = ftp_login($connection, $this->ftp_user, $this->ftp_pass);

if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

$upload = ftp_put($connection, "/home/".$this->ftp_host."/public_html/".$file, $source, FTP_BINARY);

if (!$upload) { 
echo 'FTP upload failed!'; 
} else {
echo("UPDATED FILE ".$source." SUCCESSFULLY!<BR>"); 
}

ftp_close($connection);     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    # Declare Files
    $local_file = "/home/user/public_html/file.php";
    $remote_file = "public_html/remote_file.php";

    # FTP
    $server = "ftp://ftp.yourhost.com/".$remote_file;

    # FTP Credentials
    $ftp_user = "ftp_username";
    $ftp_password = "password";

    # Upload File
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ftp_file = fopen($local_file, 'r');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $ftp_user.":".$ftp_password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $ftp_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($local_file));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

You can easily put it in a function if this does what you want.

Comment: Hmmm that didn't seem to work either, still is returning a blank source file...I returned the $result variable and used that as my source file but the source is blank...what am I doing wrong? thank you for your help!

Comment: When you say its returning a blank source file, using the example I posted, that would be `file.php`?

Comment: Well I have my update function and I pass in the source and the filename like such: $source = $updater->getFile($file);
$updater->update($source,$file); but the $source variable is blank which tells me that the getFile function is not returning the file?

Comment: Would I just do return $result on the function you gave me to get the file and store that in my $source variable or am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: Just to get the routine working try hardcoding the filenames and paths for now.  My routine grabs the `local_file` and sends it via FTP to the server specified then saves it as `remote_file`.  You could basically replace your `getFile` function with the example routine I provided and pass the `local_file` and `remote_file` in as variables if you wanted.  I think you're adding an extra step that doesn't need to be there.

Comment: ah ha! I got you now...lol yup sorry I was adding a step that didn't need to be there...sweet let me give this a shot now that I understand. Thanks I'll let you know if it works out!

Comment: hmmm still not working...I used your code, put it into a function, hard coded the local and remote file locations like this: 
$local_file = "/home/user/public_html/cp/".$file;
$remote_file = "cp/".$file;
$file variable is being passed into the function. No luck...

Comment: bingo I got it! Just had a few errors on my end with the variables :) thank you so much!